# How to create a Lower and Upper bound column for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

enter code hereCurrently the pandas dataframe in one column is set up as

```
Allocation
8100 
8195
8195
8815
```

Trying to create a lower and upper bound column where it looks like down below. There is thousands of rows for this and I am not sure how to create this at scale using pandas.

```
Lower Bound   Upper Bound
8100                8195
8195                8815
```

Comment: Youre just asking to know how to make a new set of columns?  IF so, treat it like a Dict and assign it some value.

Comment: Do you mean one row? Your question is confusing, can you add a code example of the dataframe in question and the output you're looking for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear, but it looks like you want your data structured like so:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(2, len(df)//2), columns=['Lower_Bound', 'Upper_Bound'])
```

Output:

```
   Lower_Bound  Upper_Bound
0         8100         8195
1         8195         8815
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you need to alternate rows between upper and lower bound.

```
(df.set_index(list(divmod(np.arange(df.shape[0]),2)))
.squeeze()
.unstack()
.rename({0:'Lower Bound',1:'Upper Bound'},axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   Lower Bound  Upper Bound
0         8100         8195
1         8195         8815
```